# PHP Include: Long Path Issue

Tags: php, include

When I try to include a long file path the PHP include fails to load. A short include path works fine.

For example, the following will fail:

```
../../contents/2010-St-Louis-Rams-Tickets-Season-Package-Includes-Tickets-For-All-Regular-Season-Home-Games/inc/title.inc
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Please post your OS configuration and exact PHP error message.  It could be a true file not found error or perhaps just a permissions problem.  It isn't likely that your OS is limiting the filename length.

Comment: Code is correct because same code is working on Linux server with appachi but we have migrated site from linux server to windows 2008 server with IIS 7. It does not show any error or warning just skipped it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your path (including drive name etc) exceeds 260 characters. Because that's the maximum directory length for Windows. [Click here to see the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The reference also states that there is the possibility to create extra-long path names by prepending the path name with "\?\". That should expand the maximum path length to 32767 characters. But I have no idea if this can be used within PHP.

Comment: I see a +1 on this answer, so I was wondering if anyone was successful by using the \\?\ syntax within php? Personally I couldn't get it to work, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yep, prepending `\\?\` doesn't work. [This](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?7,627200) looks like an explanation, albeit a long one.

Comment: You are correct. Due to a bug in PHP, the long path names wouldn't work. This has been [fixed with PHP 7.1](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.0RC4/NEWS#L763).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a symfony 1.x project when writing tests that looked something like this:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../bootstrap/unit.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../../../../MY/LONG/PATH.php'
```

The thing here is that those /../../.. take a lot of character space. In my case if those were not used it would work.

In symfony you can get the root of you project by calling sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir'), and thus I could change my code in the following way:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../bootstrap/unit.php';
require_once sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . '/MY/LONG/PATH.php'
```

This works (in my case) perfectly.

Although here I use the root dir provided by the symfony framework, in your own project it's just a matter of defining the project's root dir somewhere and keep it accessible.