# MAMP PHP include failing

Tags: php, include, mamp

MAMP PHP Symfony2 local installation on Mountain Lion.

I am trying to execute a simple include

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php';
```

this resolves to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs//refactoring/base/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php

or

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//refactoring/base/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php

This always fails the include due to file not found. I have run a test and it appear that 80 characters is a limit on the length of an include path, however I just cannot find anywhere to control that. Is there a max_include_path_length variable somewhere that I can change? If not, any other suggestion?

Thanks
Chris H

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Include: Long Path Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426420/php-include-long-path-issue)

Comment: The question referred to as a possible pre-cursor is a windows installation with a suggested path length of 260 characters. I know mine is less than 120 and the failure occurs at 80 characters. I am also MAMP on MAC, so my guess was that maybe MAMP would require a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

it took some spaces,try to remove spaces...OR use like this

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../bootstrap/unit.php';

require_once sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . '/MY/LONG/PATH.php'
```

For reference use this

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however there are no spaces, and the example is the same as your first example.